# Get values from xml data in php

Tags: php, xml

I am getting output in xml format.I want to fetch each `<field>` `name` value like awb_number,order_id,actual_weight etc.How  can I get each name value.

```
 <ecomexpress-objects version="1.0">
    <object pk="1" model="awb">
    <field type="BigIntegerField" name="awb_number">700054480</field>
    <field type="CharField" name="orderid">5012</field>
    <field type="FloatField" name="actual_weight">0.5</field>
    <field type="CharField" name="origin">DELHI-DSW</field>
    <field type="CharField" name="destination">DELHI-DLN</field>
    <field type="CharField" name="customer">Ecom Express Private Limited - 32012</field>
    <field type="CharField" name="consignee">MUKESH KUMAR GUPTA</field>
    <field type="CharField" name="pickupdate">11-Feb-2013</field>
    <field type="CharField" name="status">Delivered / Closed</field>
    <field type="CharField" name="reason_code"/>
    <field type="CharField" name="reason_code_description"/>
    <field type="CharField" name="reason_code_number">999</field>
    <field type="CharField" name="receiver">mukesh 9999488339</field>
    <field type="CharField" name="expected_date">12-Feb-2013</field>
    <field type="CharField" name="last_update_date">05-Apr-2013</field>
    <field type="CharField" name="delivery_date">2013-02-17 11:26:00</field>
    <field type="CharField" name="ref_awb">None</field>
    <field type="CharField" name="rts_shipment"/>
    <field type="CharField" name="system_delivery_update">2013-02-17 11:26:00</field>
    <field type="CharField" name="rts_system_delivery_status"/>
    </object>
 </ecomexpress-objects>
```

I have tried below code but I can not display like text `awb_number,order_id,actual_weight` from xml etc.

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($server_output);
foreach($xml->object->field as $key =>$value)
{
    //foreach($element as $key => $value)
        echo($key .'-' .$value)."<br>";


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`name` is not a node value, it is a node attribute. To retrieve its value you have to use array syntax:

```
echo $value['name'];  // Output for first field: awb_number
echo $value;          // Output for first field: 700054480
```